# In .NET Core using ILogger how do I log unicode chars

Tags: logging, .net-core

I have a dependency-injected `ILoggerFactory` that generates an `ILogger` in a .NET Core 2.1 application.

I want to log something like this:

```
logger.LogInformation("Magic Char {MagicChar}", "λ")
```

The problem is that what actually gets logged is:

```
info <myClass>
     Magic Char ?`
```

How do I log unicode chars using .NET's built in logger?

Comment: Does it happen with all `ILoggerFactory`/`ILogger` or only with a specific one?

Comment: I'm using the .NET Core default one. I haven't tried any others - that's an option, but this question is really about whether the default one can handle unicode.

Comment: Theorically it is the work of the Provider how to handle unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the interfaces handles unicode perfectly.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
    .AddDebug()
    .AddConsole();

ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogInformation("Magic Char {MagicChar}", "λ");

Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Magic Char (b) {0}", "λ"));

Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

(note the use of `Console.OutputEncoding` for setting the `Console` to UTF-8)

Sadly there is a [bug in Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176587/unicode-characters-in-output-window.html), so the Output window (where the debug messages are written) doesn't handle unicode. They should have fixed it in VS 2017 15.6, but I'm using VS 2017 15.7.5 in a console program and the bug is still there (but on a different pc, on VS 2017 15.7.5 the unicode is shown correctly... who knows?).

(the `Thread.Sleep()` is because from observation the `Console` logger is "lazy" and waits a little before writing)

But you can test yourself:

```
public class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new MyLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        string formatted = formatter(state, exception);
        File.AppendAllText("output.txt", formatted, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogInformation("Magic Char {MagicChar}", "λ");
```

and take a look at the `ouput.txt` file, that should be UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: Cheers! That worked, turns out all you need for .NET Core's default is `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` in the `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: I had to set the `Console.OutputEncoding` _before_ a logger is resolved. Made it the first instruction in `Main` before even creating the host. Otherwise, I still got question marks when I set the encoding in my main `BackgroundService`.